# How to write correct test for "CreateView" in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm a rookie in coding and during my learning, I build a model for a blog. this is BlogPost model in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('pub', 'Published'), ('drf', 'Draft'))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_time_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_time_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(BlogPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_time_modification',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

for creating or editing a post, I made a form like this in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import BlogPost

class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'author', 'status']
```

and this is the create view in views.py which is supposed to redirect to the main page (or post_list) after creating a new post.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import NewPostForm
def post_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('post_list')
    else:
        form = NewPostForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_create.html', context)
```

and this is the urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list_view, name='post_list'),
    path('create/', views.post_create_view, name='post_create'),
    path('<slug:slug>/update/', views.post_update_view, name='post_update'),
    path('<slug:slug>/delete/', views.post_delete_view, name='post_delete'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail_view, name='post_detail'),
]
```

and every thing in my blog is working correctly. but I tried to write test for different parts of my blog and the test for CreateView is failing every time. this is the test I wrote for CreateView in tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from .models import BlogPost

class BlogPostTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user1 = User.objects.create(username='user1')
        cls.post1 = BlogPost.objects.create(
            title='post1',
            text='this is post1',
            slug='post1-slug',
            author=cls.user1,
            status='pub',
        )

    def test_create_new_post(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('post_create'), {
            'title': 'sample1',
            'text': 'create post test text',
            'author': self.user1,
            'status': 'pub',
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEqual(BlogPost.objects.last().title, 'create post test')
        self.assertEqual(BlogPost.objects.last().text, 'create post test text text')
```

after running the test, it said:
AssertionError: 200 != 302, and redirecting is failed. but in the website I don't have any problem with creating a new post and redirecting after that.
please help me to find what is wrong with my test or anything else I wrote.
tnx